# How to change page content by click over paper-tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, polymer, google-web-component

I have paper-tabs like this

```html
<paper-dialog id="view">  
  <paper-tabs selected="0">
    <paper-tab on-tap="_changeList">TAB 1</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab on-tap="_changeList">TAB 2</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab on-tap="_changeList">TAB 3</paper-tab>
  </paper-tabs>
  <iron-list>some story for tab 1</iron-list>
  <iron-list>some story for tab 2</iron-list>
  <iron-list>some story for tab 3</iron-list>
 </paper-dialog>
```

and i have different iron-list for each tab. First tab will be select but as user will click on other tab so content should be change for selected tab. _changeList function will be bring different data .How can i achieve this ? Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By binding `paper-tabs`'s `selected` propertry with `iron-pages`'s `selected` property will show the corresopnding based on selected tab.

```
<paper-dialog id="view">
   <paper-tabs selected="{{currentPage}}">
      <paper-tab on-tap="_changeList">TAB 1</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab on-tap="_changeList">TAB 2</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab on-tap="_changeList">TAB 3</paper-tab>
   </paper-tabs>
   <iron-pages selected="{{currentPage}}">
      <iron-list>some story for tab 1</iron-list>
      <iron-list>some story for tab 2</iron-list>
      <iron-list>some story for tab 3</iron-list>
   </iron-pages>
</paper-dialog>
```

As you want to show the first tab by defalut, you need to set the `currentPage` value to `0`

```
ready: function(){
    this.currentPage = 0;
}
```

Hope this helps :)